# remove an irregular expression using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I'm facing a problem and I'm not able to escape it.
I'm parsing a file with lines such as:

```
word1 word2 #(one, two, three) word3(x y z) word4(a b c)
etc
```

I need to remove all the substring `#(one, two, three)`, the only constraint for the recognition of this substring is that it begins with `"#(" and end with ")"`
The field number or the contents of the substring is not regular

Can you give me some suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please remove the `design-patterns' tag. your question has nothing to do with design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, I like the "term": **Irregular expression** in your question. ;)

try this line:

```
awk -F'#\\([^)]*\\)' '{$1=$1}7' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "word1 word2 #(one, two, three) word3(x y z) word4(a b c)"|awk -F'#\\([^)]*\\)' '{$1=$1}7'
word1 word2   word3(x y z) word4(a b c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

```
awk '{gsub("#([^)]*))", "", $0);}1' inputfile
```

For your input:

```
$ awk '{gsub("#([^)]*))", "", $0);}1' <<< 'word1 word2 #(one, two, three) word3(x y z) word4(a b c)'
word1 word2  word3(x y z) word4(a b c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a simple substitution on a single line, sed is perfectly adequate for this job:

```
$ sed 's/#([^)]*)//' file
word1 word2  word3(x y z) word4(a b c)
```

but if you need an awk solution:

```
$ awk '{sub(/#([^)]*))/,"")}1' file
word1 word2  word3(x y z) word4(a b c)
```

Add "g" to the end of the sed command or change sub() to gsub() in awk if the pattern can appear multiple times on each line.

Answer (score 1):

From your tags, I see you suspect awk can do it, but Perl can do it pretty nicely too:

```
perl -pe 's/#\([^)]*\)//g'
```

Or, for your full example:

```
echo "word1 word2 #(one, two, three) word3(x y z) word4(a b c)" | perl -pe 's/#\([^)]*\)//g'
```

Or, where your data is in a file:

```
perl -pe 's/#\([^)]*\)//g' your_file
```

To clarify, the RE I have used says "replace a hash, followed by an opening bracket and then any number of characters that aren't closing brackets, followed finally by a closing bracket with nothing, globally". The brackets are escaped because they are grouping operators in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about removing I think you might want to change the input file itself. You can do a find and replace in nedit.
string to find : ^#(.*)$\n
replace with :

(that is replace by nothing)